# EF Core - Adding Include results in throwing an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 7 application, using a PostgreSQL database, and utilizing EF Core for its data management.

An error occurs when attempting to retrieve a user along with their dependencies.

```cs
public async Task<Domain.Aggregates.User> GetAsync(UserId id)
        => await _users
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

The above code executes correctly.

```cs
public async Task<Domain.Aggregates.User> GetAsync(UserId id)
        => await _users
            .Include(u => u.Address )
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

Adding `.Include` for the `Address` property doesn't throw an exception, but it also doesn't retrieve address data from the database.

```cs
public async Task<Domain.Aggregates.User> GetAsync(UserId id)
       => await _users
           .Include(u => u.Address )
           .Include(u => u.Categories)
           .Include(u => u.CurrencyAccounts)
           .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == id);
```

However, adding either of the remaining two `.Include` statements results in throwing the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element.

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
   at MoneyMinder.Infrastructure.EF.Repositories.PostgresUserRepository.GetAsync(UserId id) in MoneyMinder\MoneyMinder.Infrastructure\EF\Repositories\PostgresUserRepository.cs:line 21
   at MoneyMinder.Application.User.Commands.Handlers.ChangeAddressHandler.Handle(ChangeAddress request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MoneyMinder\MoneyMinder.Application\User\Commands\Handlers\ChangeAddressHandler.cs:line 23
   at MediatR.Wrappers.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<Handle>g__Handler|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at MoneyMinder.API.Endpoints.UserEndpoints.Address(ChangeAddressRequest request, ISender sender, IUserService userService) in MoneyMinder\MoneyMinder.API\Endpoints\UserEndpoints.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.ExecuteTaskResult[T](Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass90_2.<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at MoneyMinder.Shared.Exceptions.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) in MoneyMinder\MoneyMinder.Shared\Exceptions\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 13
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_1.<<UseMiddlewareInterface>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Changing from `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` to `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and using select doesn't make any difference—the error remains the same, despite the absence of the `SingleOrDefault()` invocation.

Diagram:

[Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPaDV.png)

Account:

```cs
public class Account : AggregateRoot<AccountId>
{
    public AccountLogin Login { get; private set; }
    public AccountRole Role { get; private set; }
 
    public AccountPasswordHash PasswordHash { get; private set; }

    public User? User { get; private set; }

    private Account()
    {
    }
    
    internal Account(AccountId id, AccountLogin login, AccountRole role, AccountPasswordHash passwordHash)
    {
        Id = id;
        Login = login;
        Role = role;
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    internal Account(AccountId id, AccountLogin login, AccountRole role, AccountPasswordHash passwordHash, User user)
        : this(id, login, role, passwordHash)
    {
        User = user;
    }
    
    public void ChangePassword(AccountPasswordHash passwordHash)
    {
        PasswordHash = passwordHash;
        
        AddEvent(new AccountPasswordHashChanged(this));
    }

    public void VerifyPassword(string password, IPasswordHasher<AccountPasswordHash> passwordHasher)
    {
        var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(PasswordHash, PasswordHash.Value, password);

        if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
        {
            throw new LoginFailedException();
        }
        
        AddEvent(new AccountLoggedIn(this, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

User:

```cs
public class User : AggregateRoot<UserId>
{
    public UserId Id { get; private set; }

    public Account Account { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }
    
    public readonly List<Category> Categories;
    public readonly List<CurrencyAccount> CurrencyAccounts;
    
    public UserEmail Email { get; private set; }
    public UserName Name { get; private set; }
    public UserPhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; private set; }
    public UserGender Gender { get; private set; }
    public UserBirthDate BirthDate { get; private set; }
    
    internal User(UserId id, UserEmail email, UserName name, UserPhoneNumber phoneNumber,
        UserGender gender, UserBirthDate birthDate, Address address)
    {
        Id = id;
        Email = email;
        Name = name;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        Gender = gender;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
        Address = address;
        
        AddEvent(new UserCreated(this));
    }

    private User()
    {
    }

    public void ChangeEmail(UserEmail email)
    {
        var old = Email;
        Email = email;
        
        AddEvent(new UserEmailChanged(this, old, Email));
    }
    
    public void ChangePhoneNumber(UserPhoneNumber phoneNumber)
    {
        var old = PhoneNumber;
        PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        
        AddEvent(new UserPhoneNumberChanged(this, old, PhoneNumber));
    }
    
    public void ChangeAddress(Address address)
    {
        var old = Address;
        Address = address;
        
        AddEvent(new UserAddressChanged(this, old, Address));
    }

    public void AddCategory(string categoryName)
    {
        var category = new Category(categoryName);
        Categories.Add(category);
        
        AddEvent(new CategoryAdded(this, category));
    }

    public void RemoveCategory(string categoryName)
    {
        var category = GetCategory(categoryName);
        Categories.Remove(category);
        
        AddEvent(new CategoryDeleted(this, category));
    }

    public void ChangeCategoryName(string categoryName, string newCategoryName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //var category = GetCategory(categoryName);

        //var newCategory = new Category(newCategoryName);

        //Categories.Find(category).Value = newCategory;
        
        //AddEvent(new CategoryNameChanged(this, newCategory));
    }

    private Category GetCategory(string categoryName)
    {
        var category = Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);

        if (category is null)
        {
            throw new CategoryNotFoundException(categoryName);
        }

        return category;
    }
}
```

Address:

```cs
public class Address
{
    //private Regex universalPostalCodeRegex = new(@"^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\- ]{0,10}[a-z0-9]$");
    //private Regex houseNumberRegex = new(@"^\d{1,4}[A-Z]$");
    
    public AddressStreet Street { get; }
    public AddressPostalCode PostalCode { get; }
    public AddressHouseNumber HouseNumber { get; }
    public AddressApartmentNumber? ApartmentNumber{ get; }
    
    public User User { get; private set; }

    public Address(string street, string postalCode, string houseNumber)
    {
        // if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(street) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(postalCode) ||
        //     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(houseNumber))
        // {
        //     throw new EmptyUserAddressException();
        // }
        //
        // if (!universalPostalCodeRegex.IsMatch(postalCode) || !houseNumberRegex.IsMatch(houseNumber))
        // {
        //     throw new InvalidUserAddressException(street, postalCode, houseNumber);
        // }

        Street = street;
        PostalCode = postalCode;
        HouseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public Address(string street, string postalCode, string houseNumber, string apartmentNumber, User user)
        : this(street, postalCode, houseNumber, apartmentNumber)
    {
        User = user;
    }

    private Address()
    {
    }
    
    public Address(string street, string postalCode, string houseNumber, string apartmentNumber) 
        : this(street, postalCode, houseNumber)
    {
        ApartmentNumber = apartmentNumber;
    }
}
```

Category:

```cs
public class Category
{
    public CategoryName Name { get; init; }
    public User User { get; private set; }
    
    public Category(CategoryName name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Category(CategoryName name, User user)
        : this(name)
    {
        User = user;
    }
}
```

CurrencyAccount:

```cs
public class CurrencyAccount : AggregateRoot<CurrencyAccountId>
{
    public CurrencyAccountId Id { get; private set; }
    public CurrencyAccountName Name { get; private set; }
    
    public User User;

    public readonly List<Balance> Balances = new();
    public readonly List<Income> Incomes = new();
    public readonly List<Payment> Payments = new();
    public readonly List<FutureIncome> FutureIncomes = new ();
    public readonly List<FuturePayment> FuturePayments = new();
    
    internal CurrencyAccount(CurrencyAccountId id, CurrencyAccountName name, User user)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        User = user;
        AddEvent(new CurrencyAccountCreated(this));
    }

    private CurrencyAccount()
    {
    }
    
    private void AddNewBalance(Currency newCurrency, decimal amount)
    {
        Balances.Add(new Balance(newCurrency, amount));
        AddEvent(new NewCurrencyAdded(this, newCurrency));
    }
    
    private void AddFutureIncome(FutureIncome futureIncome)
    {
        if (FutureIncomes.Exists(f => f.TransactionName == futureIncome.TransactionName))
        {
            throw new FutureIncomeAlreadyExistException(futureIncome.TransactionName);
        }

        FutureIncomes.Add(futureIncome); 
        AddEvent(new FutureIncomeAdded(this, futureIncome));
    }
    
    private void AddFuturePayment(FuturePayment futurePayment)
    {
        if (FuturePayments.Exists(f => f.TransactionName == futurePayment.TransactionName))
        {
            throw new FuturePaymentAlreadyExistException(futurePayment.TransactionName);
        }
        
        FuturePayments.Add(futurePayment);
        AddEvent(new FuturePaymentAdded(this, futurePayment));
    }
    
    private FutureIncome GetFutureIncome(string transactionName)
    {
        var futureIncome = FutureIncomes.Find(ft => ft.TransactionName == transactionName);

        if (futureIncome is null)
        {
            throw new FutureIncomeNotFoundException(transactionName);
        }

        return futureIncome;
    }
    
    private FuturePayment GetFuturePayment(string transactionName)
    {
        var futurePayment = FuturePayments.Find(ft => ft.TransactionName == transactionName);

        if (futurePayment is null)
        {
            throw new FuturePaymentNotFoundException(transactionName);
        }

        return futurePayment;
    }
    
    public void AddPayment(Payment payment)
    {
        if (Balances.Exists(b => b.Currency == payment.Currency))
        {
            Balances
                .Single(b => b.Currency == payment.Currency)
                .ChangeAmount(payment.Amount);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NoCurrencyInAccountException(payment.Currency);
        }
        
        Payments.Add(payment);
        
        AddEvent(new PaymentAdded(this, payment));
    }

    public void AddNewRecurringPayment(RecurringPayment recurringPayment)
    {
        (Payment payment, FuturePayment futurePayment) = recurringPayment.Separate();
        
        AddFuturePayment(futurePayment);
        AddPayment(payment);
    }
    
    public void AddFollowingPayment(FollowingPayment followingPayment) 
    { 
        var oldFuturePayment = FuturePayments
            .Find(ft => ft.TransactionName == followingPayment.TransactionName);
        
        if (oldFuturePayment is null)
        {
            throw new FuturePaymentNotFoundException(followingPayment.TransactionName);
        }

        (Payment payment, FuturePayment futurePayment) = followingPayment.Transform(oldFuturePayment);

        DeleteFuturePayment(followingPayment.TransactionName);
        AddPayment(payment);
        AddFuturePayment(futurePayment);
    }

    public void AddIncome(Income income)
    {
        if(Balances.Exists(b => b.Currency == income.Currency))
        {
            Balances
                .Single(b => b.Currency == income.Currency)
                .ChangeAmount(income.Amount);
        }
        else
        {
            AddNewBalance(income.Currency, income.Amount);
        }
        
        Incomes.Add(income);
        
        AddEvent(new IncomeAdded(this, income)); 
    }

    public void AddNewRecurringIncome(RecurringIncome recurringIncome)
    {
        (Income income, FutureIncome futureTransaction) = recurringIncome.Separate();
        
        AddFutureIncome(futureTransaction);
        AddIncome(income);
    }

    public void AddFollowingIncome(FollowingIncome followingIncome)
    { 
        var oldFutureIncome = FutureIncomes
            .Find(ft => ft.TransactionName == followingIncome.TransactionName);
        
        if (oldFutureIncome is null)
        {
            throw new FutureIncomeNotFoundException(followingIncome.TransactionName);
        }

        (Income income, FutureIncome futureIncome) = followingIncome.Transform(oldFutureIncome);
        
        DeleteFutureIncome(followingIncome.TransactionName);
        AddIncome(income);
        AddFutureIncome(futureIncome);
    }

    public void DeleteFutureIncome(string futureTransactionName)
    {
        var futureIncome = GetFutureIncome(futureTransactionName);

        if (futureIncome is null)
        {
            throw new FutureIncomeNotFoundException(futureTransactionName);
        }

        FutureIncomes.Remove(futureIncome);

        AddEvent(new FutureIncomeDeleted(this, futureIncome));
    }
    
    public void DeleteFuturePayment(string futureTransactionName)
    {
        var futurePayment = GetFuturePayment(futureTransactionName);

        if (futurePayment is null)
        {
            throw new FuturePaymentNotFoundException(futureTransactionName);
        }
        
        FuturePayments.Remove(futurePayment);
        
        AddEvent(new FuturePaymentDeleted(this, futurePayment));
    }

    public void CurrencyConversion(Currency from, Currency to, decimal amount, double coefficient)
    {
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            throw new NegativeAmountException(amount);
        }

        Payment payment = new Payment(DateTime.UtcNow, from, (amount * -1), "Currency Conversion", "Currency Conversion");
        
        var convertedAmount = (decimal)((double)amount * coefficient);
        
        Income income = new Income(DateTime.UtcNow, to, convertedAmount, "Currency Conversion");
        
        AddPayment(payment);
        AddIncome(income);
    }
    
    public void ChangeAccountName(CurrencyAccountName name)
    {
        var oldName = Name;

        Name = name;
        
        AddEvent(new CurrencyAccountNameChanged(this, oldName, Name));
    }
}
```

AccountConfiguration:

```cs
internal sealed class AccountConfiguration 
    : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.Aggregates.Account>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Domain.Aggregates.Account> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Accounts);
        builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

        builder
            .Property(a => a.Id)
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value, id => new AccountId(id))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.Login)
            .HasConversion(l => l.Value, l => new AccountLogin(l))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.Role)
            .HasConversion(r => r.Value, r => new AccountRole(r))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.PasswordHash)
            .HasConversion(ph => ph.Value, ph => AccountPasswordHash.Create(ph))
            .IsRequired();
        
        builder
            .HasOne(a => a.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.Account)
            .HasForeignKey<Domain.Aggregates.User>()
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

UserConfiguration:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
using MoneyMinder.Domain.Entities;
using MoneyMinder.Domain.Enums;
using MoneyMinder.Domain.ValueObjects;


namespace MoneyMinder.Infrastructure.EF.Config;

internal sealed class UserConfiguration :
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.Aggregates.User>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Address>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Domain.Aggregates.User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Users);
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);

        builder
            .Property(u => u.Id)
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value, id => new UserId(id))
            .IsRequired();
        //Relations
        
        //CurrenycAccount
        builder
            .HasMany(u => u.CurrencyAccounts)
            .WithOne(ca => ca.User)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        //Address
        builder
            .HasOne(u => u.Address)
            .WithOne(a => a.User)
            .HasForeignKey<Address>()
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        //Category
        builder
            .HasMany(u => u.Categories)
            .WithOne(c => c.User)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        //Properties
        builder
            .Property(u => u.Email)
            .HasConversion(e => e.Value, e => new UserEmail(e))
            .IsRequired();
        builder
            .Property(u => u.Name)
            .HasConversion(un => un.ToString(), un => UserName.Create(un))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(u => u.PhoneNumber)
            .HasConversion(pn => pn.ToString(), pn => UserPhoneNumber.Create(pn))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(u => u.Gender)
            .HasConversion(g => g.Value, g => new UserGender(g))
            .IsRequired();
        
        builder
            .Property(u => u.BirthDate)
            .HasConversion(bd => bd.Value, bd => new UserBirthDate(bd))
            .IsRequired();
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Addresses);
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.Street)
            .HasConversion(s => s.Value, s => new AddressStreet(s))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.PostalCode)
            .HasConversion(pc => pc.Value, pc => new AddressPostalCode(pc))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.HouseNumber)
            .HasConversion(hn => hn.Value, hn => new AddressHouseNumber(hn))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(a => a.ApartmentNumber)
            .HasConversion(an => an.Value, an => new AddressApartmentNumber(an))
            .IsRequired(false);
    }

   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
   {
       builder.ToTable(TableNames.Categories);
       builder.Property<Guid>("Id")
           .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

       builder
           .Property(c => c.Name)
           .HasConversion(n => n.Value, n => new CategoryName(n));
   }
}
```

CurrencyAccountConfiguration:

```cs
internal sealed class CurrencyAccountConfiguration : 
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Domain.Aggregates.CurrencyAccount>, 
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Balance>, 
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Income>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<Payment>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<FutureIncome>,
    IEntityTypeConfiguration<FuturePayment>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Domain.Aggregates.CurrencyAccount> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.CurrencyAccounts);
        builder.HasKey(ca => ca.Id);

        builder
            .Property(ca => ca.Id)
            .HasConversion(id => id.Value, id => new CurrencyAccountId(id))
            .IsRequired();

        builder
            .Property(ca => ca.Name)
            .HasConversion(n => n.Value, n => new CurrencyAccountName(n))
            .IsRequired();
      
        builder
            .HasMany(ca => ca.Balances)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        builder
            .HasMany(ca => ca.Incomes)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder
            .HasMany(ca => ca.Payments)
            .WithOne()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
        builder
            .HasMany(ca => ca.FutureIncomes)
            .WithOne()
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder
            .HasMany(ca => ca.FuturePayments)
            .WithOne()
            .IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Balance> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Balances);
        
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id");
        
        builder.Property(b => b.Amount);
        builder
            .Property(b => b.Currency)
            .HasConversion(GetCurrencyConverter());
            
        
    }
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Income> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Incomes);
        
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id");
        builder.Property(i => i.TransactionName);
        builder.Property(i => i.TransactionDate);
        builder.Property(i => i.Amount);
        builder
            .Property(i => i.Currency)
            .HasConversion(GetCurrencyConverter());
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Payment> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.Payments);
        
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id");
        builder.Property(p => p.TransactionName);
        builder.Property(p => p.TransactionDate);
        builder.Property(p => p.Amount);
        builder.Property(p => p.Category);
        builder
            .Property(p => p.Currency)
            .HasConversion(GetCurrencyConverter());
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FutureIncome> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.FutureIncomes);
        
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id");
        builder.Property(i => i.TransactionName);
        builder.Property(i => i.TransactionDate);
        builder
            .Property(i => i.Currency)
            .HasConversion(GetCurrencyConverter());
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FuturePayment> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(TableNames.FuturePayments);
        
        builder.Property<Guid>("Id");
        builder.Property(p => p.TransactionName);
        builder.Property(p => p.TransactionDate);
        builder.Property(p => p.Category);
        builder
            .Property(p => p.Currency)
            .HasConversion(GetCurrencyConverter());
    }
    
    private ValueConverter<Currency, string> GetCurrencyConverter()
    {
        return new ValueConverter<Currency, string>(c => c.ToString(), c => Currency.Create(c));
    }
}
```

So far, I've tried everything that might come to mind for a beginner programmer.

Comment: Does adding `.AsSplitQuery()` solve the problem?

Comment: Try to use instead of `SingleOrDefault`, `ToArray` and analyze which duplicate has been retrieved.

Comment: Check the SQL that is being generated here, it's hard to tell because you have posted too much code, but I suspect a mismatch in your models?

Comment: Remove this: u => u.Id == id and add it to a where clause. Then use FirstOrDefaultAsync or toListAsync.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes After adding this, the error disappeared, but the data still doesn't load into the User object

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried this before writing the post; unfortunately, it resulted in the same error, despite not using SingleOrDefault()

Comment: @GHDevOps I tried this before writing the post; unfortunately, it resulted in the same error, despite not using SingleOrDefault()

Comment: @DavidG I suspected that possibility as well. I've been studying the code I wrote for a week now, looking for any differences between the generated database and the model, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue may be arising from a circular reference between User and Category, where a Category has a reference back to User. In accordance with Domain-Driven Design (DDD) principles, and considering that User is treated as an Aggregate Root, it's advisable to refrain from having direct links to a User in other entities not being Aggregate. As a resolution, you may want to consider removing the User property from Category.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597171/can-aggregate-root-reference-another-root) is a question that resembles your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the issue. To fix the error, it was enough to add .AsSplitQuery(). However, even after resolving the error, the data still doesn't get retrieved from the database.